# Why does this code generates pseudo-random numbers?

Tags: random

I am reading this page : http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm
where the following function is used to create random numbers with no explanation :

```
function IntNoise(32-bit integer: x)             

    x = (x<<13) ^ x;
    return ( 1.0 - ( (x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);    

  end IntNoise function
```

Is there any way explanation as to why this generates "random" number, or any proof as to why the number generated are truly random (ie have a sufficiently high entropy)?

thanks

Comment: Nothing is truly random.  Define sufficiently high.

Comment: @SLaks : I actually have no idea, I'm just asking if anyone can provide me with the reasoning behind this formula, other than "let's do random operations with prime numbers so that the result would appear random"

Comment: @awoodland : I think the purpose of this particular function is that it maps any int with a "random" number, which you cannot do with rand() without additional storage

Comment: Why is this tagged C and C++?

Comment: This code is not C++ or C, as the tags say (I think, though I am not sure, that it is Basic or Visual Basic)

Comment: I read it as "the next two lines are C or C++" in which case it does make sense

Comment: You have used three different terms in your question: pseudo-random, truly random, and high entropy.  Technically speaking, the only "entropy" that you will have when you use this function is the seed that you pass to it (32-bits). Everything else is deterministic. It is definitely not "truly random". I think this implies your question is open-ended and too discussiony for this QnA style and a better way to get an answer is to study up random number generation in textbooks.

Comment: This code maps an input value (`x`) to a number that bears little obvious resemblance to that input. In that way, it's the moral equivalent of a `rand` function that takes a seed. Both are completely deterministic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all PRNGs, the entropy output is bounded by the entropy input.  So it is at least as non-random as `rand()` (which is not random at all).

George Marsaglia developed a suite of tests known as the "Diehard tests" ([website](http://www.stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/), [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests)) which test for certain useful properties of PRNGs, with the hope that any PRNGs with those properties is intuitively likely to be useful for whatever problem you need a PRNG for.  You can run those tests on `IntNoise`, if you like.

It is likely that the `IntNoise` function you give is not good as a general purpose pseudorandom number generator.  General purpose pseudorandom number generators are hard to come by, most people reuse the same few over and over again.  However, `IntNoise` is stateless, which is a nice property and uncommon.